# kendo freezed(locked) grid height

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui

We are using a grid with a few elements as locked.
We have set minimum and maximum height of the grid using css.

```
.k-grid-content {
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
```

We are facing issue setting the height of the locked grid. If we don’t set height of grid, a number of rows on the locked side get whitened at the bottom.
So how do we dynamically set the height of grid?

This is what we have on Onbound event

```
var grid = e.sender;
var lockedContent = grid.wrapper.children(".k-grid-content-locked")
var content = grid.wrapper.children(".k-grid-content");

if (content[0] && (content[0].scrollWidth == content[0].clientWidth))
    lockedContent.height(content.height());
else
    lockedContent.height(content.height()-16);
//16 is near to horizontal scroll height
grid.resize();
```

This is a hack and it is not working perfectly as in grouping.
We have gone through this link 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Layout/change-grid-height-when-using-frozen-columns
But it doesn’t work as it assumes no height set on grid at all.

Can some one please provide the right solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared a dojo for you to try out to see if that works for your scenario

http://dojo.telerik.com/eSava/2

All I have done is created a function that does all the grunt work for you.

```
    function initializeGrid(options)
{
    if(options === null || options === undefined)
    {
        options = {
            size: 0.55,
            gridContentCss: ".k-grid-content",
            gridLockedContentCss: ".k-grid-content-locked",
            gridsToResize:[]
        };
    }


    var windowHeight = $(window).height() * options.size;

    if(options.gridsToResize !== null && options.gridsToResize.length > 0 )
    {
        options.gridsToResize.forEach(function (item) {
            var gridContent = $('#' + item + ' > ' + options.gridContentCss);


            var lockedContent = $('#' + item + ' > ' + options.gridLockedContentCss);


          //  console.log(gridContent, lockedContent);

            gridContent.height(windowHeight);

            if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
                lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

            }
        }); 
    }
    else 
    {
        var gridContent = $(options.gridContentCss);
        var lockedContent = $(options.gridLockedContentCss);

        gridContent.height(windowHeight);

        if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
            lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResizeGrid(options);
    });

}
```

in it's default state when this is called it will resize all grids to 55% of the windows height.

but if you want to apply different sizing rules you can by providing a simple variable like so:

```
 var gridResize = {
            size: 0.4, 
             gridContentCss: ".k-grid-content",
            gridLockedContentCss: ".k-grid-content-locked",
            gridsToResize:['grid']
          }


initializeGrid(gridResize);
```

so in the above example it will override the default and resize the grid to 40% of the available screen size. In addition it will only resize the control with the id of grid. So if you had multiple grids on the screen at once then the function will them alone and preserve there heights.

Any issues let me know.

Comment: Great explanation! But my scenario is little bit different, probably simpler. Basically for all our grids we have .k-grid-content {   max-height: 400px;   min-height: 0px;} So all grids resize automatically if the data is less and for  large data it is 400px size with pagination. In one of the grids using locking we want a similar behavior. But that requires grid height to be set so programtically we are trying to set it. I have provided the code being used above but that doesnt work properly, probably something wrong with scroller height as I have assumed it as    16.

Comment: I have altered my code so you can now use either percentage or pixel height as an option: http://dojo.telerik.com/eSava/5  Note the pixel height is being applied to the content portion only at the moment so if you wanted to adjust so the entire grid is set to 400px max height then you could subtract the height of the grouping/pager etc.

Comment: But the height is not variable.In cases where there are few records the grid needs to adjust.If we need a fixed height then I think we can simply set the height(say to 400) while creating the Grid and that seemingly works fine. Without freeze our grid height varies between minsize and maxsize and same we want to achieve with Freezed Grid.But if we dont give height in some cases(like few records) the freezed part of grid becomes whitened at the bottom.